# Page_ClientValidate is not a function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, client-side-validation

I have a client side code i'm running on localhost which works fine, but when i copy the same files to the server which runs the site, and try to do the same, the site fails to run the same code.

Specifically, this code:

```
var flag = window.Page_ClientValidate('vgPerosnal');
```

It works fine when i run it through localhost, but when i get to this line through the website, i get the next error in chrome debugger:

> Uncaught TypeError: window.Page_ClientValidate is not a function

I checked to see if there function is really missing, but the file "WebUIValidation.js" which holds the function is copied as well.

I searched the web for hours for solutions with no luck.
Please help me.

Comment: is `WebUIValidation.js` getting loaded into the page. please check the console to ensure it. sounds like a path issue

Comment: The aspx page "inherits" from Site.Master, which have the following line:


`<asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** it turns out it was a bigger problem. 
[the answer to it is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31365925/webforms-scripts-only-works-in-debug-mode)

<s>**OLD:** *After hours of searching i didn't find the perfect answer, including trying to reinstall .NET framework, but i managed to overcome the problem.
i copied this line to the code:</s>

```
<script src="/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js"></script>
```

and now it works.