# WebForms scripts only works in debug mode

Tags: .net, scripting, webforms

I have a site with forms a `validationGroup` and `LinkButton` to handle them, which calls `WebForm_PostBackOptions`. the problem is `WebForm_PostBackOptions` works only on localhost (debug?), but when I copy it to the production on a remote server I get the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions is not defined

I have the following code:

In **Site.Master:**

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

...

```
 <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=272931&clcid=0x409 --%>
            <%--Framework Scripts--%>
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery.ui.combined" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
            <%--Site Scripts--%>
        </Scripts>
    </ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

In **BundleConfig:**

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/WebFormsJs").Include(
              "~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js",
              "~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js",
              "~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js",
              "~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js",
              "~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js",
              "~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js",
              "~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js",
              "~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/MsAjaxJs").Include(
            "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjax.js",
            "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxApplicationServices.js",
            "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxTimer.js",
            "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js"));

        // Use the Development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you’re
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
            "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));
    }
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but taking off the `~` from the path statement fixed the problem!

```
<asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
```